# pintool to intercept writes and VirtualProtect

Tags: operating-systems, pintool, system-call

On Linux the *strace.so* pintool gives a good overview on how system calls are intercepted in PIN. One could monitor the value of `EAX` to see which system call is being invoked(and mprotect and writes could be intercepted in the fashion).

How could we do something similar for Windows? I see that the `int 2e` interrupt is used to trap into the kernel and that the system calls numbers are given at [here](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/ntapi/). Is `NtWriteFile` the analogue of `write`? Also is `NtProtectVirtualMemory` the analogue of `mprotect`?

Comment: I might have a bad understanding of your question, but pintool is suppose to work also for Windows. Haven't you tried it for Windows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pintools on Windows can also aid you in instrumenting system calls. Also, if its discovered that the cpu supports `sysenter`/`syscall`, those are used in place of `int 2e`. However, this has no bearing on whether or not instrumentation can take place.

To answer your second question, yes, `NtReadFile`, `NtWriteFile` and `NtDeviceIoControlFile` are the *nix equivalent of `read`/`write`/`ioctl`.